# Ionic not rendering new tabs locations

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

I am making new thing in ionic the scenario is :-

1] Page 1 , which contain list of items and three tabs
    (i) When I clicked on item then it will go to details page and there all three tab will be replace by new three tabs and its back button should be common such I clicked on second tab and want to go back list of item , this thing should be there.
    (ii) The new tabs not working properly as per requirements,

So anybody have something for that.

Please let me know.

Regards

Comment: you can try this... http://codepen.io/Glitchbone/pen/GEcae

Comment: Its not upto  the mark , actually I also need back button which will be common for all tab, But thanks for replay.

Comment: "common for all tab" what do you mean by it? 
1. Do you need common button like home on all tabs header which navigate to home page ?
2. do you want back button on all pages which navigate to previous page?

please clarify your question then we can help you

Comment: Suppose I have a page which have following contents:

Comment: Suppose I have a page which have following contents:
1] list of items & at bottom tab (three tab) 
2] Tab 1 for same page 
3] Tab 2 for another list of items 
4] Tab3 for simple static paragraph 
Now main thing
1] Suppose I clicked on tab1 which has list of items and I clicked on any single item 
2]  Then details related to the item will be show + back button at top + replace all tab with new three tabs
3] All new three tab will have common back button at top 
4] All new tab is regarding the item details such as personnel details tab , attendance tab and contact tab

Comment: means in details sub pages Tabs you need common back button which you navigate to main tab page right?

Comment: OK, I understand @shivam i'll get back to you

Comment: Yes , that is I want